# How to split elements of .csv into two separate lists

Tags: python, split

So I am given a file with min and max values ordered as such:

```
12.0,-4.5
34.6,1.8
12.7,2.8
etc...
```

For the purposes of my program, I need to take each line and split it, putting one "column" of values in one list and the second "column" in another. This way I will be able to use all the first values for a calculation of average/min/max, and all the second values can be used for a separate calculation.

So far, I have only been able to achieve splitting each line into separate elements, like this:

```
['12.0,-4.5'], ['34.6,1.8'], ['12.7,2.8'], etc...
```

But I want it to be:

```
['12.0', '34.6', '12.7', etc...] and ['-4.5', '1.8', '2.8', etc...]
```

My code is as follows. I have tried to do sufficient commenting, but if you need further explanation (which I doubt) let me know!

```
#import libraries to be used
import time

fileChoice = input("Enter the file name: ") 
inputFile = open(fileChoice)

catTypes = inputFile.readline().strip('ï»¿\n').split(',') #the headers of the file, taking away special characters
numOfHeadings = len(catTypes) #determining how many headers there are
print(catTypes) #printing the headers for future reference
rowCount = sum(1 for row in inputFile) #counting rows for later use
inputFile.close()

li = open(fileChoice) #opening file again for data collection
li.readline()

li = [entry.split() for entry in li] #creating list for every line in .csv file
print(li)
```

The main portion of the list confusion is the last four lines, how would I modify this to accompany my two list idea?

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Use a context manager to handle file objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split each line, and append `row[0]` to one list, `row[1]` to the other list.

```
import csv

mins = []
maxs = []

with open(fileChoice) as f:
    f.readline() # Skip header line
    csvin = csv.reader(f)
    for row in csvin:
        maxs.append(row[0])
        mins.append(row[1])
```

Comment: It is asking me for an argument in the csv.reader(), what must this argument be?

Comment: Oh of course, how dumb of me! This works, now I just need to figure out the formatting of each list and may come up with some more issues that need solving!

Comment: What if I want to omit the first element of my list? These are headers that say 'Max' and 'Min', I don't want these to be a part of my calculations as they might mess things up...

Comment: Call `f.readline()` before the `for` loop to skip the first line in the file.

Comment: Could this be adapted if the file that was chosen had 10 or more  columns? Or this a completely different problem?

Comment: Yes, easily. Although with lots of columns it would be easier to use a list of lists instead of separate variables. Loop over the columns and then append to the corresponding element of the list.

Comment: `for i, val in enumerate(row): l[i].append(val)`

Comment: Yeah, I figured it would just include adding variables. I'll probably want to do a list of lists.

Comment: So I am trying to use a while loop to sort all the elements into a main list before sorting that into more lists. Why is this not working? ```forCalculations = []
i = 0 
while i <= columns:    
    for row in inputFile:
        forCalculations.append(row[i])
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: Oh man, that looks ugly. I need to learn how to format comments

Comment: Comments don't support much formatting. Post a new question. I'm not really sure what you're trying to do with that.